# Upload file to NodeJS server every 30 minutes

Tags: python, perl, file-upload, node.js

I'm trying to figure out the best way to upload a file to a NodeJS(any server I guess, but just being specific) every 30 mins.

I was thinking about using perl or python to acheive this, or even NodeJS or a CGI script?

Would it be best to just create a multi-part form?

Trying to figure out the best practice.

Thanks.

Comment: Any programming language that can open a network connection will do. You should pick one you're comfortable with. As-is this question is too broad to answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this isn't part of other program logic, a simple `curl --upload-file <file> <url>` would do the job. If not, like Dan Grossman commented, any language capable of opening a socket and write HTTP headers and body would work (all assuming your node.js server is speaking http).

Comment: exactly what I was looking for. Just didn't know a more concise way to ask it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I might recommend crontab for a job like this.  It's a sort of job-scheduler for the operating system, and is designed for 'do this job every so often' tasks.